# Can a witness avoid testifying based on lack of memory?

Tags: united-states, evidence, testimony

If a witness has been deposed and effectively denied having any recollection of events relevant to a case, can that testimony be used to keep her from taking the stand?

I'm imagining something like a motion in limine relying on either Rule 401 or 403.

I'm looking not for deductions based on experience or the text of the rules, but for case law addressing the issue.

Comment: I would have thought it would be rather difficult to rely on such a witness. "In your deposition you said you didn't remember, but now you say you remember it perfectly...." would seem an obvious start for cross examination. Given this, why would either side *want* to call this witness?

Comment: The scenario I'm imagining involves calling an adverse witness with the expectation that they'll stick to their deposition testimony and that the jury will draw adverse inferences from it.

Answer (score 3):

You can be called on, and then you would say you do not remember or whatever is the truth.

The judge can rule your testimony is not needed if it is excessive or is not relevant, but that would happen as an objection after you are called or subpoenaed.

https://ilr.law.uiowa.edu/print/volume-103-issue-4/an-epistemological-argument-against-federal-rule-of-evidence-403s-cumulative-evidence-clause/

Comment: Why can't the witness be excluded on 403 grounds?

Comment: If it would be excessive or something the judge can say your testimony is not needed, but that would happen after you are called on.

Comment: Why can't it be done through a motion in limine?

Comment: Usually those motions are in regard to a specific thing not a person. For example, the judge would say that you cant talk about X, but you would still have the right to call a person to talk about Y.

Comment: Sometimes witnesses are excluded. I am not saying they aren't in all cases, but each side has the right to try to call you then the other side would object or the judge would say your testimony is not needed. It may be ruled that you don't have to testify, but the party wanting your testimony has the right to ask that you do even if it is eventually overruled.

Comment: @bdb484 It would be very, very unlikely for a judge to grant a motion in limine on that ground. The fact that someone doesn't remember something in a deposition doesn't necessarily imply that the person won't recall it later on at trial. Perhaps a motion in limine might be granted, however, if someone had advanced Alzheimer's disease and the disruption to the witness would outweigh the benefit to the court.

Comment: I assume that's correct; I'm just having a terrible time trying to find authority on this point.

Comment: @bdb484 some things are just up to the judge. If you are looking for case law specific to that, you may not find it, since case law in the books comes from appellate courts and in this case the local judge would make the decision.